Upgrade path from v1.1 to latest stable (v1.15?)
We have a network that is in production and running on polkadot-sdk v1.1. We are wondering what the possible upgrade paths are to upgrade this to latest. We did something similar in the past from substrate 2 to substrate 3 where we extracted all migrations that affected our pallets, but I'm not sure if this is what we want to do here.
